# CKFinder change the default view settings to list when link button in CKEditor is clicked

Tags: ckeditor, ckfinder

I am trying to set the defaultview to list when some one clicks link on CKEditor. I have already configured CKFinder with CKEditor. So now when i click links in CKEditor, I see a browse button and `onclick` of browse button it takes me to file list. But there it shows images as thumbnails. I want to display it as "list". I should do this only when I click links in CKEditor. If I click images it should show me the thumbnails.

The following is the way I created my CKEditor and associated it with my CKFinder.

```
function createCkEditor(textAreaId, width, height) {
    var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( textAreaId,
        {
            customConfig : 'suConfig.js',
            width : width,
            height : height
        });

    CKFinder.setupCKEditor( editor, { basePath : '/CKFinderJava/ckfinder/', id:'123', startupPath : varStartupDir, startupFolderExpanded : true, rememberLastFolder : false} ) ;
}

CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev ) {
    // Take the dialog name and its definition from the event data.
    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

    // If "Link" dialog
    if ( dialogName == 'link' ) {
        alert('link dialog clicked');
        // Remove extraneous tabs
        dialogDefinition.removeContents( 'target' );
        dialogDefinition.removeContents( 'advanced' );

        // Set default URL
        var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents( 'info' );
        var urlField = infoTab.get( 'url' );
        urlField['default'] = contentUrl;
    }

    // If "Image" dialog
    if ( dialogName == 'image' ) {
        // Remove extraneous tabs
        dialogDefinition.removeContents( 'Link' );
        dialogDefinition.removeContents( 'advanced' );

        // Set default URL
        var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents( 'info' );
        var urlField = infoTab.get( 'txtUrl' );
        urlField['default'] = contentUrl;
    }
});
```

`CKEditor.on` will be called if you click an option in CKEditor. I am not sure how to get the CKFinder instance associated with the current editor and set default view to list. I am using JavaScript and JSP.

Answer (score 0):

i did find the solution for this.

In config.js which is in CKFinderJava.war/ckfinder directory make the necessary configurations.
    config.defaultViewType_Images = 'thumbnails';
    config.defaultViewType_Files = 'list';
this is settings for Images and Links from ckeditor. If you want all the displays to be as list then
    config.defaultViewType = 'list';